# Return count on click before submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-datalayer

On a ticketing page, I'm trying to track the amount of clicks of `tickets` added to the cart so I can pass the value through to the Google Tag Manager dataLayer. I've written the following function:

```
// Increment/subtract count on user click
function updatef1a2cCounter(count) {
    var count = 0;
    $('.ticketf12c .add-amount').click(function () {
        count++;
    });
    $('ticketf12c .subtract-amount').click(function () {
        count--;
    });

    return count;
}

// Get and return current count. Push to dataLayer
$('.test-submit-button').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(updatef1a2cCounter());

    dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'productDetail',
        'ecommerce': {
            'detail': {
                // Family tickets   
                'products': [{
                    'name': 'Ticket Type Name Goes here',
                    'id': '',
                    'price': '100.00',
                    'brand': 'Some Brand',
                    'category': 'Ticket',
                    'quantity': updatef1a2cCounter()
                }]                    
            }
        }
    });

});
```

I have the click event counters working correctly when someone adds and subtracts and item, but when I hit the submit button, the count always returns `0`. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: You are adding event handlers to  $('.ticketf12c .add-amount') every time you click $('.test-submit-button') - you are then returning 0

Comment: Becuase your ticketf12c click event handler is not trigged.

Comment: You also have a missing dot in your selector `.ticketf12c .subtract-amount`

Comment: @mplungjan thank you. Tired eyes and did not see this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove function `updatef1a2cCounter`. Move below code to outside `updatef1a2cCounter`. And use `count` directly instead of `updatef1a2cCounter()`.

```
var count = 0;
$('.ticketf12c .add-amount').click(function () {
    count++;
});
$('.ticketf12c .subtract-amount').click(function () {
    count--;
});
```

Below is complete code.

```
// Increment/subtract count on user click
var count = 0;
$('.ticketf12c .add-amount').click(function() {
  count++;
});
$('.ticketf12c .subtract-amount').click(function() {
  count--;
});

// Get and return current count. Push to dataLayer
$('.test-submit-button').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(count);

  dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'productDetail',
    'ecommerce': {
      'detail': {
        // Family tickets   
        'products': [{
          'name': 'Ticket Type Name Goes here',
          'id': '',
          'price': '100.00',
          'brand': 'Some Brand',
          'category': 'Ticket',
          'quantity': count
        }]
      }
    }
  });

});
```

---

> I have the click event counters working correctly when someone adds and subtracts and item.

I am sure that your click event will not be working, unless you have called `updatef1a2cCounter()` from elsewhere. It will start work after you click `submit button`. Also as you were using `var count = 0` at initial lines of `updatef1a2cCounter()` and then `return count;` so it always return `0`.

Comment: But missed a typo. :/

Comment: @mplungjan, thanks to pointing that out. Updated the answer.

Comment: I guess I should not have wasted time commenting OP's original question before answering....

Answer (score 1):

You are adding event handlers to  `$('.ticketf12c .add-amount')` every time you
click `$('.test-submit-button')` - you are then returning the 0 you set in the beginning

Also you are missing a dot in `.ticketf12c` selector here:

`$('.ticketf12c .subtract-amount').click(function() {`

You likely meant to use

```
'quantity': count
```

and add the event handlers on page load like this:

```js
let count = 0;

$(function() { // on page load

  $('.ticketf12c .add-amount').click(function() {
    count++;
  });
  $('.ticketf12c .subtract-amount').click(function() {
    count--; // you may want to test for negative here?
  });
  // Get and return current count. Push to dataLayer
  $('.test-submit-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(count);

    dataLayer.push({
      'event': 'productDetail',
      'ecommerce': {
        'detail': {
          // Family tickets   
          'products': [{
            'name': 'Ticket Type Name Goes here',
            'id': '',
            'price': '100.00',
            'brand': 'Some Brand',
            'category': 'Ticket',
            'quantity': count // no function needed
          }]
        }
      }
    });

  });
});
```